# Python SQLAlchemy full-text searching in Postgres

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a Postgres database and am attempting to implement full-text searching via SQLAlchemy. I'm following along with the documentation, but the sample code provided causes an error and I can't get past it.

I can implement the full-text searching via the postgres commandline, but I just cannot get SQLAlchemy to play along.

The code below is basically straight from the documentation https://sqlalchemy-searchable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html 
(I added an omitted library, added the library name to the call for create_engine, put parentheses around the print statement for python3's sake)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from   sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from   sqlalchemy_searchable      import make_searchable, search
from   sqlalchemy_utils.types     import TSVectorType
from   sqlalchemy.orm             import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

make_searchable()

class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id            = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name          = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))
    content       = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText)
    search_vector = sa.Column(TSVectorType('name', 'content'))



engine = sa.create_engine('<mypostgresconnectionstring>')

sa.orm.configure_mappers()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

article1 = Article(name=u'First article', content=u'This is the first article')
article2 = Article(name=u'Second article', content=u'This is the second article')


session.add(article1)
session.add(article2)
session.commit()


query = session.query(Article)
query = search(query, 'first')

print(query.first().name)
```

When I attempt to run this code, I get hit with the following error messages:

```
AttributeError: 'comparator_factory' object has no attribute 'match_tsquery'


AttributeError: Neither 'AnnotatedColumn' object nor 'comparator_factory' object has an attribute 'match_tsquery'


AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Article.search_vector has an attribute 'match_tsquery'
```

Comment: Just a guess (and read the docs you linked): you should add a call to `make_searchable()` after you've created `Base`.

Comment: Sorry, just updated it. make_searchable(). I left it out of this example. Even with the make_searchable call, i'm still confronted with the same errors.